# Can I delete SQL Server setup bootstrap log files and is there a setting to manage these automatically manage this?

Tags: sql-server, azure

On one of our azure VM's we have over 60GB of data in the folder

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log
```

I'm wondering what the best way is to manage this? Would there be an issue if I delete these? Is there a setting where these can be deleted or compressed automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove log files under `Setup Bootstrap\LOG\`; these are not needed for SQL runtime. The setup log files may be useful to troubleshoot issues even in the future.

You may consider to compress them and store them anywhere, just in case you ever need to troubleshoot SQL setup.

[See this MSDN forum discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b71f7b93-91d7-4ce1-a4cf-21425f830712/is-it-safe-to-remove-bootstrap-log-files-sql-server-2005?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade).